# grapejs add internal script as well as external script to canvas

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

As of now I have

```
const editor = grapesjs.init({
            // Indicate where to init the editor. You can also pass an HTMLElement
            container: '#gjs',
            canvas: {
                scripts: ['https://somelink.js', 'https://anotherlink.js]
            },
});
```

I would like to have this link as well as some scripts which are internally added, say

```
function alertMe() { alert('Ninja') }
```

I am unable to add the above function block into the canvas `scripts`. Anybody have an idea?

**Note:** It is not possible to create separate file for these script because these are extracted during run time

Answer (score 0):

The custom component can help to load your custom javascript logic. Follow this https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Components-js.html#dependencies.
You can even add a custom component by default to editor  'editor.addComponents({ type: "your-custom-component" })'